# Regions in my scene seem to render with less illumination

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I have a simple problem in my scene:
I have 4 lights, but only central lights are working in my render.

[image]
[image]
More info:

I tried more lights or planes, more emission strength, but the illumination don't penetrate inside of cylinder, the cylinder is cutted in half.. only the central  illumination(Normal illumination) is working good.

My goal is a illumination equal to the object's center (normal illumination) for all parts of the object

This render will be used for texture of another object, but is still a draft, ignore the number of polygons ...

Comment: Please state your goal for illumination.   Example Scenario 01.  I want the scene to have 4 bright spots and otherwise rather dark.  Example Scenario 02.  I want the scene to be rather brightly lit everywhere.   You might also change your great annotations to also state SUCCESS or FAILURE.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend? This would be the easiest way for us to get a sense of what you are trying to achieve, and what is actually happening.

Comment: My objective is a illumination equal to the center of the object (Normal illumination)

Comment: I posted more information and my blend file!!!

Comment: Sorry for not being overly helpful here but if your aiming to create a texture, for something else (I assume an HP bar from the title of the blend file), why not use something like Paint or Photoshop? I feel like your making you life too complex, but I might have misunderstood the question... :)  Also use a single directional light with no attenuation if you want everything to be lit evenly.

Comment: Sorry, i'm noob in image editor, will be made several bars using the same illumination and mesh, but other materials, the illumination is not uniform !!!
Thanks man
Obs: isn't a HP bar, It's a Active Time Battle. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the caps from either end seems to help light bounce correctly.

[image]

[image]

Or instead of deleting the cap, detach it from the vertices around it.
[image]

Comment: I had tested it with 900 in all, but I do not have success !!!!

Comment: Good, this is not a best solution, but solves my problem :D

Comment: You can also detach that cap/fan instead of deleting it. that works too.

Comment: Thanks, now i have illumination in my texture, i will remake the object, for had more detail and organization...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Since you have stated you are new to Blender, sometimes deleting objects, lights and other items removes subtle mistakes. Archive your file under a new name, so this operation is very little risk.  The second time you model these objects will be faster than the first.
- Delete all the lights and add them back. Logic stated in bullet 1.
- Delete the whole scene and start from scratch.  Logic stated in bullet 1.
- I assume you want brightness everywhere.
- Add more lights or raise your lights higher along the z axis.  Increase the strength.
- Add a more distant larger plane. Orient its face towards your scene. Select the emission shader. See image below.

[image]

- If desired select Cycles Ray Visiblity Camera to FALSE unchecked. This will prevent the render from showing a bright rectangle.  See image below.

[image]

- Verify you are satisfied with the render results.

Comment: I tried more lights or planes, more emission strength, but the illumination don't penetrate inside of cylinder, the cylinder is cutted in half.. only the central  illumination is working good.

Comment: I suggest you consider the new bullet points above. What do you mean inside the cylinder.  Is the cylinder transparent?  Do you mean on the cylinder?

Comment: check my blend file...